# can any argument in regionMatches() method can make the method return true for a string in uppercase and lowercase?

Tags: java, string

i am a student and was doing some practice with strings in java,i came across regionMatches() method, i came to know that  it is case sensitive, therefore on running the following program where i am comparing a part of str1 with str2,

```
String Str1 = "my dog's name is bruno";
String Str2 = "bruno";
String Str3 = "BRUNO";
System.out.println(Str1.regionMatches(17, Str2, 0, 5));
```

this gives the output as true, but as this is case sensitive , therefore, upon executing the following one, where a part of str1 is compared with str3

```
String Str1 = "my dog's name is bruno";
String Str2 = "bruno";
String Str3 = "BRUNO";
System.out.println(Str1.regionMatches(17, Str3, 0, 5));
```

it gives output as false.
i want to know if there's any way by which it can ignore the case?

Comment: Aside: you don't need to use `new String("Bruno")`. `"Bruno"` is a String already, and for what you are doing the identity of the strings is irrelevant (and indeed is *almost always* irrelevant).

Comment: thankyou for pointing that, i did forget that. i have corrected it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [another signature of the same method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#regionMatches-boolean-int-java.lang.String-int-int-) which takes a boolean as the first argument indicating whether case should be ignored.

```
public boolean regionMatches​(boolean ignoreCase,   //<<<
                             int toffset,
                             String other,
                             int ooffset,
                             int len)
```

Comment: can you please give me an example, how to use this? i read it, but was not able to get it completely.

Comment: @Sid `Str1.regionMatches(true, 17, Str3, 0, 5)`